# AvalonEdit and Abstract Margin Scrolling together Memory Leak

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks, uiscrollview, avalonedit

I have next problem with my project.
I have had to add `AbstractMargin` to my `AvalonEdit` control to create some of bookmarks/breakpoints.

When i put my `AvalonEdit` control into `ScrollViewer`, `AbstractMargin` scroll and work good. 
**BUT!**
When I now open some document, especially BIG, `ScrollViewer` cause memory leaks. Using of memory is growing exponentially finally causing crash of my app.

(`ScrollViewer`- 450MB RAM used, no `ScrollViewer`160MB RAM only 1 small document opened!)

When I delete `ScrollViewer`and using only scrolling from AvalonEdit control, my `AbstractMargin` is not scrolling.

Can u help me - how can i scroll avalon with added margin...

```
   ...
 <DataTemplate >
     <ScrollViewer 
         Background="Transparent" 
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
         HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
         PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel"
     >
     <avalonEdit:TextEditor 
         x:Name="TextEditor"
         Document="{Binding DokumentTekstowy, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
         IsModified="{Binding Edytowany, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         IsReadOnly="{Binding TylkoDoOdczytu}"
...
```

In Code Behind I am adding margin

```
t.TextArea.LeftMargins.Insert(0, z);
```

where z is

```
public class ZakladkaMargines : AbstractMargin
{ 
    protected override HitTestResult HitTestCore(PointHitTestParameters hit)
    {
        return new PointHitTestResult(this, hit.HitPoint);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        return new Size(20, 00);
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       ...
    }
```

The result is I can scroll avalon with my margin, but when open big document a lot of Rect and other visualtext objects are made, memory leak, app crashes.

If I delete `ScrollViewer` and use

```
<avalonEdit:TextEditor 
       ...

    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
>
```

No memory leak, good performance, but my added margin do not scrolling.

Comment: You should not need to wrap the `TextEdit` control in a `ScrollViewer`.  Do you see a similar growth in memory if you add a `LineNumberMargin` to your editor (_without_ wrapping the editor in a `ScrollViewer`)?  If not, compare your implementation to that one.  Make sure you're rendering content relevant to the currently visible lines in the text area.

Comment: I have added my code down here

Comment: LineNumberMargin is added from the beggining and works good.

My AbstractMargin is not causing memory leak, because even if I will not add it, app crashes. 

Memory leak reasone is wrapping TextEditor into external ScrollViewer.

Comment: That's not surprising, because when you put your `TextEdit` control in a `ScrollViewer`, it's giving itself enough space to accommodate _the entire document_ (as opposed to just enough space to fit into the window).  **Do not wrap your `TextEdit` it in a `ScrollViewer`**; that is the *wrong* thing to do.

Comment: Ok, thank You for explaining.

Now, how can I scroll my abstractMargin  along with texteditor?

Comment: I would need to see what your `OnRender` method looks like.  Alternatively, you could look at the source code for `LineNumberMargin` and see how _that_ implementation stays in sync with the visible text area.  It's only a few hundred lines of code to look through.

Comment: I think I have found source of the problem,
when i clicked margin i get line in this way:

       var p = e.GetPosition(texteditor.TextArea).Y;

where e is MouseEventArgs.

On OnRender method I use 

   var a = textView.GetVisualLine(i + 1);

where a is y position.
Maybe problem is here

Comment: Sounds about right.  I had a feeling you weren't properly restricting your rendering to the lines in view, and the `GetVisualLine` method looks like the solution.  Good luck!  I hope you it working.